# Logstash parse data within square brackets

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse the following log-data:

```
[2016-Nov-12 13:15:17] [prog.HELP]: Some sample text, that causes some troubles. Please use module.html. Watch: https://wiki.buybite.org/display/FOP/Dash+mash+dust [] []
```

When I try to parse, I cannot parse inside square brackets.
I've used this script:

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTH}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %\[{WORD}\]
```

But it didn't help at all.
I have tried to check it on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Please check your data, `2016-Noc-12` contains `Noc`, month name, is it true?

Comment: It was a typo :)

Comment: I hope my answer below helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The expression did not work because there is a `]` square bracket after seconds.

Your `%\[{WORD}\]` pattern is wrong, it matches `%[{WORD}]`, as `%` cannot be torn away from the pattern name. You can use `%{DATA}` to obtain the contents between two brackets.

Use

```js
%{YEAR}-%{MONTH}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}\] \[%{DATA}\]
```